# DPlyr summarize variable arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to calculate many different statistics using summarize. How can I do something like in the example below?

Eg in this example, I would want to generate a table with counts for each month with the days that have a temperature less than 60,61... up to 90 degrees.

```
aq = airquality
aq %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarize(num_days_60=sum(Temp<60), num_days_61=sum(Temp<61) .... num_days_90=sum(Temp<90))
```

The output should look like this

```
Month   num_days_60 num_days_61 ... etc all the way up to 90 for example
5       8           8
6       0           0
7       0           0
8       0           0
9       0           0
```

Comment: the airquality dataset is included in base R. I'll include some output in my post.

Comment: I think it may be better to loop to get the output you wanted.  Something like `sapply(split(aq$Temp, aq$Month), function(x) sapply(60:90, function(y) sum(x<y)))`

Comment: Is the objective to plot these results? If so, I'd go with `plot(ecdf(Temp))` instead of constructing these numerous intermediate columns.

Comment: If you want a dplyr solution `aq %>% group_by(Month) %>% do( data.frame(t(sapply(60:90, function(y) sum(.$Temp <y))))) %>% data.frame()`

Comment: Thanks for the answers they are all good but I realize my example is bad as my data actually has four variables (three factors and a continious variable) intead of the three (fac Day, fac Month, cont Temp) in this example. I'm gonna look for a better example (my data is hundreds of thousands of rows and not really good example).

Comment: you can give us a subset of your actual data with `dput(head(yourData, 10))`

Comment: Thanks for all of the input, I was able to overcome this problem using another approach, inspired by some of your suggestions.